# Override/Add IdentityConfiguration in chlild application

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, saml

I am creating a Custom STS (using .NET 4.5) that authenticates using issuedTokenAuthentication (SAML 1.0 & SAML 2.0) tokens and issues binarytokens.
The Custom STS is child application of another .NET 4.5 web application that uses WIF and the parent application has `<identityConfiguration>`.
This is preventing me from adding `<identityConfiguration name="idConf">` in Custom STS although I specify name. I get the error during STS startup -

```
Parser Error Message: ID1024: The configuration property value is not valid.
Property name: ''
Error: 'An item with the same key has already been added.'
```

Without `<identityConfiguration name="idConf">` the STS starts but SAML token validation fails in WCF `System.ServiceModel tokenValidation`, even before RST reaches the Custom STS logic with errors related to `audienceUris`, issuer, certificate validation etc.

Here is snippets from web.config file -

```
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration name="idConf" >
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <securityTokenHandlers name="STSTokenHandlers" >
        <clear/>
        <securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
          <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
          <audienceUris mode="Never" />
        </securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add type="CustomHandler.CustSaml2SecurityTokenHandler, CustomSTS.Business" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
...
<system.serviceModel>
...
<behavior name="WSTrustServiceBehaviour">
  <serviceCredentials identityConfiguration="idConf" >
    <issuedTokenAuthentication audienceUriMode="Never" certificateValidationMode="None" >
    </issuedTokenAuthentication>
  </serviceCredentials>
  <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
  <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
</behavior>
...
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WSTrustServiceBehaviour" name="CustomSecurityTokenService">
        <endpoint name="WSTrust13HttpEndpoint" address="" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WS2007FedttpBinding" contract="System.ServiceModel.Security.IWSTrust13SyncContract" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I also tried to programmatically create `var idConfig = new System.IdentityModel.Configuration.IdentityConfiguration("idConf");` & initialize it but in this case I get an error -

```
ID7012: No <identityConfiguration> element with the name 'idConf' was found in the <system.identityModel> configuration section.
```

How can I add `<identityConfiguration>` in child application without clashing with parent applications `<IdentityConfiguration>`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out multiple options, it seems that option of declaring multiple identityConfiguration is limited to one application either parent or child. If parent web.config has  in web.config then child application cannot clear or override it. 
However, if parent application programmatically creates identityConfiguration then child application web.config can create it's own identityConfiguration.